# How do i Authenticate user using Okta without redirecting to Okta login

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, okta

I want to Authenticate my Application using okta java API.Currently based on the given code, i am getting redirected to okta, i enter my credentials and then it kicks me back to the app but my requirement is to enter my credentials in my login screen and authenticate using okta in background upon verification and successful login send me over to my app dashboard.

https://github.com/okta/samples-java-spring/tree/master/custom-login

Comment: You could use Okta's Sign-In Widget for that. https://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using OKTA with my customized login page, here are the steps :

1) First to clarify, OKTA SSO works on following things :

```
  issuer, // authentication server 
  redirectUri, // where to redirect post authentication
  clientId, // for what particular app you are seeking authentication, this should be whitelisted in OKTA
  scope: 'openid profile email' // Things you want to give access to
```

2) There is a combination of encoded ( Client Key + Client Secret ) not encrypted, 
you send as an Authorization header while helps in doing the handshake part, 
since **Client Secret must** not be sent from client side and is kept on server side only. // If you are not following this, your site is at high risk of impersonation

3) Now, you can have similar look and feel of your website in OKTA, you can do so in appearance section under customization.

[image]

4) Now for the perfect fit for your question, last but not the least, you can use [OKTA Auth SDK](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/06/13/add-authentication-angular-pwa?_ga=2.127215437.1926110623.1563862711-958958049.1549514502#authenticating-with-the-okta-auth-sdk) to write custom login page and drive it.

```
npm install @okta/okta-auth-js --save
```